# Python script to extract the particular string and related timestamp w.r.t string from log text file

Tags: python

I have a file named `log.txt` which is formatted like this:

```
Wed Oct 16 16:48:55.322 2013] [   23.923652] warning: `zygote' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.470 2013] [   35.071554] lowmemorykiller: lowmem_shrink: convert oom_adj to oom_score_adj:  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.479 2013] [   35.079038] lowmemorykiller: oom_adj 0 => oom_score_adj 0  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.479 2013] [   35.084666] lowmemorykiller: oom_adj 1 => oom_score_adj 58  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.506 2013] [   35.090390] lowmemorykiller: oom_adj 2 => oom_score_adj 117  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.506 2013] [   35.096195] lowmemorykiller: oom_adj 4 => oom_score_adj 235  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.506 2013] [   35.102037] lowmemorykiller: oom_adj 9 => oom_score_adj 529  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.506 2013] [   35.107808] lowmemorykiller: oom_adj 15 => oom_score_adj 1000  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:06.753 2013] [   35.356038] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:08.505 2013] [   37.099758] `eth0: link up`, 10 Mb/s, half duplex, flow control enabled  
[Wed Oct 16 16:49:08.505 2013] [   37.106453] eth0: link up, 100 Mb/s, full duplex, flow control enabled
```

Now I wanted to extract from the above value the string `"eth0: link up"`, the corresponding timestamp `"16:49:08.505"` and the corresponding  value  `"37.099758"`.

The output should look like:

```
String            timestamp             time spent  
eth0: link up     16:49:08.505            37.099758
```

I don't know that much python -- can anyone help me on this?

@iblazevic

As Above Situation i was having some more requirements..so i tried some code. Logs wiil be the same as above.

Now OUTPUT: if the string is present inside log.txt then it should print respective TimeStamp
 OR If the string is not in the log.txt it should show me String Not Found

```
String                  timestamp             time spent  
eth0: link up          16:49:08.505            37.099758
SPI Controller probe    NOT FOUND
i2c /dev entries driver NOT FOUND
```

i tried with Following code .. But i am getting some thing different Output.
Can u please help me on this..

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import re 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Log file parse to check Boot time log')
parser.add_argument('-f','--logfile', help='logfile to filter', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

log_patterns = [
 {'pattern':'sys_init start'},
 {'pattern':'Image verified,start/Start Bootloader'} ,
 {'pattern':'Kernel image decrypt'},
 {'pattern':'verify Kernel image passed'},
 {'pattern':'Start kernel at 0x01008000'},
 {'pattern':'Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel'},
 {'pattern':'SPI Controller probe'},
 {'pattern':'i2c /dev entries driver'},
 {'pattern':'net eth0:'},
 {'pattern':'Network_init/eth0: link becomes ready'},
 {'pattern':'eth0: link up'},
 ]

with open(args.logfile,"r") as f:
read_data = f.read()
for line in read_data.splitlines():
    for ikey in log_patterns:
        if ikey['pattern'] in line:
            match = re.search(ikey['pattern'], line)
            if match:
                temp = line.replace('[','').split(']')
                print "{0:50}{1:30}".format(ikey['pattern'],temp[0], temp[1])
            else:
                print "{0:50} {1:30}".format(ikey['pattern'],'NOT FOUND')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show some Python code and maybe others can help.

Comment: I edited my question with code which i tried.But still i am stuck. Can any help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started, you can work on it and improve it:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    read_data = f.read()
    for line in read_data.splitlines():
        if "eth0: link up" in line:
            temp = line.replace('[','').split(']')
            print "eth0: link up  {0} {1}".format(temp[0], temp[1])
```

EDIT:

Hi, here's an edit for your question, hope it helps:

```
for line in read_data.splitlines():
    for ikey in log_patterns:
        if ikey['pattern'] in line:
            match = re.search(ikey['pattern'], line)
            if match:
                temp = line.replace('[','').split(']')
                #changed line below
                print "{0:20}{1:30}{2:20}".format(ikey['pattern'],temp[0], temp[1])
            else:
                print "{0:50} {1:30}".format(ikey['pattern'],'NOT FOUND')
```

Comment: Now I am getting this kind of logs in my txt file now i want to extract timestamp..I tried to modify ur suggested code for the getting the below timestamp ...but i was fail..can u please help me on this. actually some times i am not getting [] barckets ..                                                              

06-06 13:21:41.840 D/TvMediaPlayer( 2584): ZAP_MEAS: TVMP.Reset   
06-06 13:21:41.840 V/MediaPlayerService( 1575): [3] reset  
06-06 13:22:41.840 V/TvPlayerBase( 1575): TvPlayerBase::reset

Comment: can you provide new logs and can you provide code that you have, code you tried to make it work

Comment: i edited my question with code.Can you check why it is giving me wrong output.

Comment: i edited my question can you help me out on this...

Comment: I put an example of what you can try, hope this is what you were looking for, also if it's done please mark question as answered